Issues with Synchronizing RTSP Streams in GStreamer Pipeline
I'm currently working on a project that involves synchronizing two RTSP streams to capture stereo video every 30 seconds. Initially, everything functions smoothly, with frames synchronized to the millisecond during the first hour. However, after that, I occasionally encounter frozen frames, which disrupts the video capture.
Is there a better way to handle RTSP streams in GStreamer for long-duration captures?
Here’s the GStreamer pipeline I’m using:
gst-launch-1.0 -e \ rtspsrc location='{CHANNEL_1}' ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! decodebin ! videoflip method=counterclockwise ! m.sink_0 \ rtspsrc location='{CHANNEL_2}' ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! decodebin ! videoflip method=counterclockwise ! m.sink_1 \ videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=1080 ! x265enc ! h265parse ! splitmuxsink async-finalize=true location='videos/{CAGE_NAME}_%05d.hevc' max-size-time={VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS} 
